# Why is sort -k5nr not a syntax error?

Tags: bash, sorting

```
$ ls -l | sort -k 5 -n -r
$ ls -l | sort -k5nr
```

I find out these two command generate the same output.
But I don't understand why I can combine `5` with `n`?
Why not a syntax error?

**edit:**

```
$ ls -l | cut -d: -n -f 2    
$ ls -l | cut -d:nf2
cut: the delimiter must be a single character
Try `cut --help' for more information.
```

Why `cut` dose not behave like `sort`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `sort` is implemented in a way that parses these in the way you expect.

See also [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Command-line_option):

> - Sometimes options and their arguments are run together, sometimes separated by whitespace, and sometimes by a character, typically : or =. Thus "Prog -fFilename", "Prog -f Filename", "Prog -f:Filename", "Prog -f=Filename".
> - Some programs allow single-character options to be combined; others do not. The switch "-fA" may mean the same as "-f -A", or it may be incorrect, or it may even be a valid but different parameter.

This looks like a combination of both (works without whitespace, and combination of single-character options).

---

They are simply different programs whose argument parsing is implemented differently.

In `coreutils` 8.13, compare the following::

- `src/sort.c` line 4315, invoking the special integer parsing function `parse_field_count`, that returns with the first invalid character (i.e. once the number value is finished and the next option starts): That's why `sort` can handle your arguments.
- `src/cut.c`, line 803 ff., simply using the regular `getopt` behavior of interpreting everything until the next white space as parameter to the current option.

Comment: does `sort` follow the general rule? `cut` doesn't work that way.

Comment: @kev Added additional explanation to my answer.