# Why do many CLI apps take a "--" argument?

Tags: command-line, shell, command-line-arguments

I've seen many command line tools that take a "--" argument. For example:

```
gem install mysql -- —–with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

What does it stand for? Does it have a special meaning?

Comment: Duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean , not http://superuser.com/questions/372203/whats-the-difference-between-one-dash-and-two-dashes-for-command-prompt-paramet

Comment: This is not a duplicate, I'm asking a different question here. I'm wondering about the doubledash with no argument name following.

Comment: Which is what I said, to the best of my comprehension.

Comment: Right, my bad. I was referring to the duplicate link created by @Sathya.

Comment: I've reopened it, @zmode. My apologies.

Comment: @Sathya you cannot close as duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean ?

Comment: @OlivierLalonde No, can't close as duplicate on another site

Answer (score 6):

It means the tool should stop treating the dash as an option character. For example, suppose you want to search for a dash character in a file:

```
grep -- - file
```

In your example the `--` is necessary because the gem tool is calling another tool, which also uses dash-prefixed options.

Answer (score 4):

This is common practice when one program, that takes long options, needs to call another program that also takes long options. It signals the first program to stop parsing options, and pass the rest on, unchanged, to the subprocess that it invokes.