# Running a batch file command with arguments

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

I'm creating a script to do some repetitious `OpenSSL` work, but cannot seem to get the batch file to execute the commands.

Once the file has navigated to the correct directory, I try running:

```
openssl x509 /in:in_cert.cer /inform:DER /out:out_cert.pem /outform:PEM
```

...but the batch file can't seem to handle it. The slash/colon approach was added [after research](https://superuser.com/questions/745951/dash-or-slash-in-batch-file).

The issue seems to be around the arguments, resulting in an `unknown option /in:in_cert.cer` error. Note that I've also tried the standard `-parameter argument` approach as well.

Where am I going wrong with the batch?

---

**Update:** the issue isn't in the command itself (I can run it standalone from the command line with `-`'s instead of `/`'s... it's getting the command to run *within a batch file*.

Comment: To test if it is a batch file issue, have you tried it from the command line? I seriously doubt this is anything to do with batch files.

Comment: Did you even do openssh -?  and openssl /? and see what it said.  This linkhas it using dash. http://www.ucs.cam.ac.uk/support/windows-support/winsuptech/iis/opensslcert

Comment: Love the downvote. I've definitely tried it from the command line - that's where the result/error was captured. The dash has been replaced after researching about passing arguments in batch file commands (link in original question) - not arbitrarily.

`openssh` doesn't apply; the process is `openssl`.

Answer (score 3):

Answer for any Googlers - the issue was not in the passing of the parameters to `openssl`, it was in the *encoding of the batch file itself*.

Once I changed the encoding in my editor ([Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)) to `Windows-1252`, the batch ran the commands with ease and didn't need any special `/`-instead-of-`-` approach.

Comment: +1 for solving it but you didn't troubleshoot it very well, you should have tried other commands in the batch file, and no doubt you'd then have realized that within the batch, it wasn't the openssl command specifically. Even dir /? would've given an error if the issue was the encoding and the slash. Though granted nobody suggested that troubleshooting step.

Comment: Other commands (`echo`, `cd`, `set`, etc) were working- this isn't the first time I've written a batch file :) Glad it's solved and hopefully this'll save some headache for others later.

Comment: try `echo /`  if the encoding is UTF-8 then it is a bit funny.  And `dir /?` fails. dir /? fails with "'´╗┐dir' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."  with utf-8.  What encoding did you have?

Comment: It was originally set to `UTF-8` by default (which didn't raise flags for me) - probably `Notepad++`'s default encoding... `Windows-1252` fixed it.