# What's the difference between "-h" and "--help"?

Tags: linux, macos, shell

Sometimes I see `-h` is a manual for a application, and sometimes I find `--help` in the manual.

What is the difference between them? Is there any history/story about this?

Comment: This isn’t a bad question, but there is no generic reason why this exists. Some apps use one convention, others use another. That’s it. No deep rationale or logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard place for documentation about unix commands is the unix manual (aka "man pages") ([sections 1 and 8](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/what-do-the-numbers-in-a-man-page-mean)), accessed via the `man` command. For instance, to get the documentation for the `grep` command, you'd use `man grep`.

Some commands *also* provide some built-in documentation if run with an option like `-h` or `--help`. This isn't nearly as standard, and how and whether this is provided varies a great deal between commands. As for the difference between `-h` and `--help`, that's mostly historical. The "standard" for command options in unix has evolved quite a bit over the decades.

When unix was first "born", different commands took options in completely different formats; this early chaos survives in a few commands like `tar` (which tends to assume its first argument is options whether or not it starts with `-`) and `dd` (which sort of treats all its arguments like long options without `--`).

But it didn't take long for a standard of sorts to appear: options started with a single dash, and consisted of a single letter or other character, and they had to come before any positional (non-option) parameters. This was before many commands included any built-in help, so commands from this era often use `-h` for something other than help (for instance, `grep -h` doesn't print filenames where `grep` would).

More recently, several additions to this "standard" have appeared: long options that start with a double dash (e.g. `--help`), allowing options to come after or in amongst the positional parameters, and using `--` to indicate the end of options (so everything after that is a positional parameter, even if it starts with dash). Some commands use these new option styles, some don't.

Also recently, some commands have included/added built-in help. How this gets invoked depends, basically, on the whim of the command's developer(s), along with whether `-h` already had some other meaning (as in cases like `grep`). So some commands take `-h` for help, some take `--help`, some both, and some neither.

Ironically, the best way to find out how to get the built-in help for a command (if it exists), is to read its man page. Here's an excerpt from `man grep`:

```
 -H      Always print filename headers with output lines.

 -h, --no-filename
         Never print filename headers (i.e. filenames) with output lines.

 --help  Print a brief help message.
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically `--help` is used, but if `-h` works too, developers have probably included it to make it quicker to type.

It's not standard however and very dependent on the command - `vim` uses both for example, and `bash` only uses `--help`.

As such, if you're using Linux, `man command` is typically the definitive help guide.

You might also enjoy reading [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/372203/whats-the-difference-between-one-dash-and-two-dashes-for-command-prompt-paramet#372261) for more info on command line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

`-h` short attribute is intended to save time of user which types a command(s), sometimes very long;

`--help` attribute is intended for bash scripts (which should be easy to understand by many users). In this example `-h` is obvious but sometimes there are a lot of attributes so using `-j`, `-i` `-g` in bash script is correct - bash script will execute correctly, but  your colleague from work probably will kill you :)

Answer (score -1):

It really depends on the specific program. There may be no difference between them. --help may provide more verbose text than -h .