# How bash help command generates help text?

Tags: command-line, bash

I came to [this stack question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1832/why-do-some-commands-have-man-pages-and-other-commands-use-help) and answers explaining, that some bash commands doesn't have manual, so `help` command might be used to generate some help. But what I am not really understanding how the help text is created.

> `--help` is mostly programming in nature

States that site. What does it mean help is the programming nature? It generates it from comments in the command source file?

Wikipedia states on that command that

> It provides online information about available commands... ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Help_(command)&oldid=1106209804))

But where it retrieves that information? Somewhere at the actual distro database?

Comment: Does [documentation - Difference between help, info and man command - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19451/difference-between-help-info-and-man-command/159817#159817) answer your question?

Comment: @DavidPostill So it has some text for each command in itself and just point to certain section to print it on screen, or there is a file, which opens it, or every shell command has a small text file with such information? I don't think, this answers the question.

Comment: It can be any of those things depending on how it was written.

Comment: BTW, [from this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1387312/1768872), I understand that `help` is not the same thing as `--help`. While `help` is a command, the `--help` is not obligatory function of each command. But testing it, it looks, they may work on the same principle.

Comment: What bash commands have no manual? Why not try `man bashbuiltins`.

Comment: @Bib I dont know, but I have encountered some. `man bashbuiltins` doesnt work to me, so cant tell what you mean. But if you point to `man bash`, I quote it above as not clear.

Comment: You stated `some bash commands doesn't have manual`, what are they?

Comment: I dont document them, but for example `cd`.

Comment: Tl;Dr: ask for a site recommedation in [meta.se]. I don't think that this question is a good fit for this site as it looks to be about how  operative system utility internally works. AFAIK this is not something that computer users can modify / customize. I'm wondering if it might be on topic in  [cs.se]. By the other hand if you are looking for guidance about what should be included in a self-learning plan that help you to understand how this works I think that you might get such guidance in [cseducators.se].